# Load/Connect automatically to the Linux server session using Mputty

Tags: ssh, cat, vi, putty, connection-sharing

Looking for a help on Loading the putty sessions through Mputty.

I can login to my app servers(Linux) only through Jumphost. After login to jumphost i need to perform the ssh to connect my App servers.

Is there a way to store the app server connection to connect automatically from jumhost.
FYI - In jumhost all commands are restricted. We can only use the "SSH". cd,cat,vi everything blocked.

Looking for a solution or atleast to know the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible if admin forbade it.

In one case, I had a user on a jump-server who had a .profile with just two commands:

```
ssh user@host
exit
```

So once that user logs in to the jump-server, he enters a password for real one and logouts from jump once the session on the real one ends.

But you need to be able to modify your profile on jump server. Talk with admin - I do not see other ways.